# how to change the username of a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

This may be a basic problem in the database world but I don't speak 'databaseian' fluently.

I am transferring a website from one hosting service to another; from server A to server B. Server B offers the service of transfer but I would like to do it myself. The website is based on WordPress.

My strategy is:

- to copy all the files from one server (A) to the other one (B) (done).
- to export the mysql database from server A into a .sql file (done).
- import the .sql file into a new database in server B so now Wordpress can talk to MySql (here is the problem).

The hosting service in server B provides the phpMyAdmin where I can import a .sql file ,the problem is that the database in server A was using a particular username (defined by them) and server B has another one (which I cannot change).

Is there a way of editing the .sql file in order to change (add) the username to the one in server B so I can import it smoothly?

Note: I have the password for the .sql database and username as well.

Update: The error shown by phpMyadmin when trying to import the .sql file is:

```
 #1044 - Access denied for user 'userServerB'@'localhost' to database 'db-server-A'
```

Many Thanks

**UPDATE**: Everything is working now. Apparently the .sql file had a line that was trying to create a new database itself. I got rid of this line and just used a pre-created database using all the rest of the .sql file and voila. Particular thanks to @daking963

Comment: Your .sql file shouldn't have any MySQL username/password details in it.

Comment: I see. So what could be the reason phpMyadmin cannot access the file as user 'serverB'?

Comment: You likely just need to change your WordPress config file to have the new database username and password.

Comment: The thins is that the database is still not loaded in MySql from server B. So the problem is not at the wordpress level (I will take care of your annotation) but at the MySql level

Comment: Try `show grants for current_user`. Maybe you don't have privileges to import files. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'userServerB'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION` This will give you full access.

Comment: I ran your suggestion in the SQL query tab and got the error :

     #1045 - Access denied for user 'userServerB'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: What does this show `show grants for current_user`.

Comment: `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'userServerB'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'blablabla'



GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `userServerB\_table1`.* TO 'userServerB'@'localhost'



GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `userServerB\_table2`.* TO 'userServerB'@'localhost'



GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `userServerB\_%`.* TO 'userServerB'@'localhost'`

Comment: have you created the database `db-server-A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database username/password is not part of the dumped database sql. It is part of the connection authentication details. You used one username/password to connect to server A, and a different one to connect to server B. The sql file is independent of this.

So, first just log in to phpMyAdmin on server B using the username/password they provided. Then, import the sql by following these steps:

```
1. Select the database you want to import into (or create a new one).
2. Click on SQL tab at the top.
3. Click "browse" next to the file upload box and select your sql file.
4. Click go to start the import.
```

UPDATE: Regarding your update showing the error message. It is trying to import the sql into a database named `db-server-A` *on server B*. Open the sql file in a text editor, and replace all instances of `db-server-A` with the name of your database on server B. Then save and repeat the steps above.

Comment: Thanks. Just when I do that is when I get the error:

#1044 - Access denied for user 'userServerB'@'localhost' to database 'db-server-A'

Do you think it can be on how I exported the database in server A?

Comment: could this something like server B does not allow me to create a database through this means?

Comment: @pedrosaurio, it looks like you need to change the *database name* in the sql file. Open up your `.sql` file in a text editor and do a text search for `db-server-A`. It might say something like `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`db-server-A\`;`. There also might be something like `USE \`db-server-A\``. Replace all instances of `db-server-A` with whatever the database name is on server B.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I just skipped that line and everything works now. Thank you very much for your time Ben

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the access details in the wp config file for the new server:
[wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)